# How does the wing planform shape help to operate the aircraft from subsonic to supersonic speeds?

Tags: delta-wing

Consider a compound delta wing aircraft with design cruise Mach number of 2:  Explain how the wing planform shape helps to operate the aircraft from subsonic to supersonic speeds

Comment: Welcome to the site. The question seems like a copy and paste assignment/homework question, which is off-topic here unless you [expand the question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/77007/edit) explaining what you've tried and what exactly is unclear. Also, see: [What are the advantages and disadvantages of a delta wing compared to a swept wing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22198/14897) and [others](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-wing).

Comment: I'm so sorry that people downvoted your question. It's a great question about the supersonic flight, and you're a new contributor too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This wing formation helps in supersonic flight because it had reduced wing surface, creating less drag. But it still allows for the lift needed at those speeds. It the concorde had normal wings, once they reached about supersonic speed, there would be so much stress put on the wings, that it would break off. There are many other reasons, for example wingtip vorteses, and reduced drag, but the main one is because of stress.

Welcome to aviation stack exchange, hope you have a great time here! (Psst... im a new contributor too.)

Comment: Don't want to discourage you, but over time you'll start to notice that when ppl post obvious student assignment questions because they can't be bothered doing the research the question is intended to require, we try to encourage them to do the homework and post only when they're stumped. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: thanks very greatful for you

Comment: @John K: Yeah, true, but what does homework mean? Because I don't really know what you mean by homework. I you could explain that, that would make my day.

Comment: @AirCanada001 if the question reads like something copied and pasted from a textbook exercise, as in "Explain how", that's a pretty good sign.  After a while on here it'll start to become obvious to you.

Comment: @John K: Thank's for explaining. I'll make sure I try to follow those guidelines.