# What are the benefits of a 'cranked arrow' delta wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, f-16

What are the benefits of the ['cranked arrow' delta wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_wing#Design_variations) that was used on the variant of the F-16, the F-16XL?
[image]
Source[enter link description here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16XL)

Comment: The goal of the cranked arrow was to have a high sweep inboard panel for low drag at supersonic speeds, and a low sweep outboard panel to provide better handling and maneuverability at subsonic speeds.[citation needed] (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16XL#SCAMP))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the different wing planforms? What are each's advantages? Where are they commonly used?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19475/what-are-the-different-wing-planforms-what-are-eachs-advantages-where-are-the)

Comment: Totally agree with @RalphJ, voting to not close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few reasons for choosing the cranked delta wing, as used in F-16 XL. The main one is to maintain comparable performances in the supersonic and sub/transonic speeds- a reason similar to the variable geometry wings, like one used in F-111, with the same disadvantages. [According to NASA](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20070003727.pdf),

> The  new  wing, common for both the -1 and -2 versions, was designed to provide the F-16 aircraft with improved supersonic performance while   maintaining comparable transonic performance to that provided by the current F-16 design.

Basically, you want to have good performance in the subsonic regime- improving the low speed handling and acceptable landing characteristics (the delta wings are not exactly known for that) and in supersonic regime- low aspect ratio and low drag. The result is a compromise, which is more often than not, more trouble than it is worth. From [this paper](http://www.icas.org/ICAS_ARCHIVE/ICAS2004/PAPERS/387.PDF):

> When compared to a delta wing, a double delta wing and cranked arrow   wing planforms indicate higher aerodynamic performance and maneuverability at high angles of attack,  because  a vortex  generated  from  the  strake  wing  (or  the  inboard  wing) stabilizes the flow on the main  wing  (or  the  outboard  ing) .. . furthermore, the outboard wing  leading-edge that has smaller sweepback angle than that of the inboard wing increases the wing aspect ratio as a whole and low-speed performance is improved.

Another issue with the cranked delta wings is its tendency to pitch up at high angles of attack.

Answer (score 8):

The main benefits are:

- High root thickness, so the wing can be made stiffer and stronger where the loads are highest.
- Better pitch stability in the post-stall region, so no AoA limit needs to be observed. The X-31 could maneuver with thrust vectoring only because its cranked arrow delta wing was more or less neutral in pitch over the full AoA range. A simple delta wing produces strong pitch-up moments in the post-stall region wich would quickly overpower the moments possible with thrust vectoring.